# Rails 4 Simple Form Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

For some reason my validations aren't working correctly.  I can submit the form if it's blank, and it gets processed by the controller.  Isn't the point of the model to validate the params before it goes to the controller?

My Controller is:

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subscriber, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  # GET /subscribers
  # GET /subscribers.json
  def index
    @subscribers = Subscriber.all
  end

  # GET /subscribers/1
  # GET /subscribers/1.json
  def show
    # This is Wrong, but You Get The Idea
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /subscribers/new
  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  # GET /subscribers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /subscribers
  # POST /subscribers.json
    def create
      @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @subscriber.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Thanks For Joining Our Mailing List!' }
          format.json { render :back, status: :created, location: @subscriber }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Error, Invalid Entry, or you are on the List Already!'}
          format.json { redirect_to :back, @subscriber.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /subscribers/1
    # PATCH/PUT /subscribers/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @subscriber.update(subscriber_params)
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Subscriber was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { redirect_to :back, status: :ok }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.json { render json: @subscriber.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /subscribers/1
    # DELETE /subscribers/1.json
    def destroy
      if @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(params[:email])
      respond_to do |format|
          if @subscriber.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Subscriber was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Something Wrong' }
            format.json { render json: @subscriber.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
      end
      else
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:error] = "Couldn't Find That Email Database!"
      end
    end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_subscriber
      @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def subscriber_params
      params.require(:subscriber).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

and my model is:

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_validation :downcase_email

    validates_uniqueness_of :email
    validates_format_of :email,:with => Devise::email_regexp
    validates_presence_of :name, :message => "Name can't be blank"
    validates_presence_of :email, :message => "Need an Email!!", on: :destroy


    private
    def downcase_email
      self.email = self.email.downcase if self.email.present?
    end
end
```

lastly my form:

```
<div class="five wide column subscriber">
  <div class="ui inverted form segment">
    <%= simple_form_for(@subscriber) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <h3 class="ui header">Join Our Mailing List</h3>
    <div class="two fields">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.input :name, placeholder: "Enter Name", required: true, error_html: { id: 'password_error'}%>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "Enter Email", type: "email", required: true%>
      </div>
    </div>
      <%= f.submit "Join", class: "ui blue submit button" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I need to supply any more information.  I hope this is an easy fix, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In `create` action, try `render action: :new` when `@subscriber.save` fails. When redirects, you lose the the object with its validations!

Comment: Ah thanks.  Is there anyway to render :back or go back, without losing the validations? I don't want to use the 'new' template.  The form is just a partial in the footer, and it would be nice to keep the errors there.

Comment: Then I would do this using only AJAX, using the option `remote: true` to simple_form_for helper. http://tech.thereq.com/post/18910961502/rails-3-using-form-remote-true-with-jquery-ujs

Comment: Does it really get processed - as in `.save` is successful? If so then Rodrigo's suggestion won't resolve this. Obvious suggestion, but did you restart your server after creating the validations?